# How to return documents that has an array contains more than one objects having similar field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a query like this

```
const papers = await Paper.aggregate([
                    { $match: filter },
                    {
                        $lookup: {
                            "from": "reviews",
                            "localField": "review",
                            "foreignField": "_id",
                            "as": "review"
                        }
                    },
                    { $unwind: "$review" },
                    { $match: { "review.reviews.reviewStatus": "SUBMITTED" } },
                ])
```

That returns the results like

```
[
  {
    _id: 5f721ca3909430bf5bf38133,
    manuscript: {
      keywords: [Array],
      title: 'Viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim. ',
      abstract: 'Ultricies leo integer',
      authors: [Array],
      fundingInfo: ''
    },
    review: {
      _id: 5f721ca5909430bf5bf38138,
      reviews: [Array]
    }
  }
]
```

The **reviews** array inside **review** object contain different reviewers review on this paper. **reviewStatus** is changed based on the reviewer review.

```
{
  _id: 5f721ca5909430bf5bf38138,
  reviews: [
    {
      invitationStatus: 'ACCEPTED',
      reviewType: 'MINOR_REVISION',
      reviewStatus: 'SUBMITTED',
      _id: 5f9d2fa9909430bf5bf3814a
    },
    {
      invitationStatus: 'PENDING',
      reviewType: 'MAJOR_REVISION',
      reviewStatus: 'SAVED',
      _id: 5f9d38223357c83460cb77df
    },
    {
      invitationStatus: 'ACCEPTED',
      reviewType: 'MINOR_REVISION',
      reviewStatus: 'SUBMITTED',
      _id: 5f9d39af3357c83460cb77e2,
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I want to get only those papers which has two or more **reviewStatus** value **SUBMITTED**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator within a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) stage after the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) that will filter the paper docs with reviews array containing
at least two submitted. The following operation shows how you to go about the pipeline:

```
const papers = await Paper.aggregate([
    { '$match': filter },
    {
        '$lookup': {
            "from": "reviews",
            "localField": "review",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "review"
        }
    },
    { '$addFields': { 
        'review': { '$arrayElemAt': ['$review', 0] }
    } },
    {  '$match': {
        '$expr': {
            '$gt': [
                { '$size': {
                    '$filter': {
                        'input': '$review.reviews',
                        'cond': { '$eq': ['$$this.reviewStatus', "SUBMITTED"] }
                    }
                } },
                1
            ]
        } 
    } }
])
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your sincere cooperation. But I am getting an empty array after adding the $match what you wrote above. I am not sure why. Would please help to figure out this?

Comment: You did a great job, your answer is almost correct. I just had to $unwind the review and  changed 'input' like 'input': '$review.reviews'

Comment: @FozleRabbiShafi I wasn't too sure what the schema for the `reviews` collection looks like but from your above remark I figured out that it has a reviews field which is an array

Comment: you are such a wonderful person. Thanks a lot again.